# Nodejs mysql get correct TimeStamp format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) and after get result from `sql` i get different `TimeStamp` format like with this:

```
created_at: Sat Jul 16 2016 23:52:54 GMT+0430 (IRDT)
```

but it is on mysql is :

```
2016-07-16 23:52:54
```

and i want to get that, not other format, how can i set this format on mysql connection or sql command?

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'a',
    database: 'signal'
});

connection.query(command, function (err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend to process rows instead of trying to change MySQL output result. This way your database will have detailed full data about the `created_date`. While clients (other functions, systems, projects, etc) will format the value retrieved from DB to whatever format they need. Moreover you will keep a consistent return results for dates through your system. Whatever DB query is executed your software will always expect the same format returned back.

Here is an example in ES6 also using moment.js library to simplify any date operations you will have, strongly recommend to use this library.

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'a',
    database: 'signal'
});

function formatDate(date) {
  return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}

connection.query(command, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    rows = rows.map(row => ({
      ...row,
      created_date: formatDate(row.created_date)
    }));

    console.log(rows);
});
```

**update** or in ES5

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'a',
    database: 'signal'
});

function formatDate(date) {
  return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}

connection.query(command, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    rows = rows.map(function(row) {
      return Object.assign({}, row, { created_date: formatDate(row.created_date) });
    });

    console.log(rows);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but whats `...row,` ? could you complete this section?

Comment: Thanks, why i get `[]` ? . problem is `Invalid number of arguments, expected 0..1` for this part of your code `{}, row, { create_date: formatDate(row.create_date) }`

Comment: I'm very sorry. I had a typo `create_date` instead of `created_date`. I fixed that in my reply. Also I have a Fiddle example right here to demonstrate how my code works https://jsfiddle.net/zperwfex/

Comment: Thanks. but in jsfiddle i get this error: `ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

Comment: @mahdipishguy add moment.js to your html page ( the one calling your js file )

Comment: @HichamZouarhi I'm using Nodejs and after install and define variable as `var moment     = require('moment');` i get this error: `TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'
`

Comment: Looks like your Node version is older and does not support Object.assign(). Look at my updated Fiddle and use a commented out version of the map() function https://jsfiddle.net/zperwfex/1/

Comment: @anvk i'm so sorry sir, i'm updated nodejs version, excuse me

Comment: @HichamZouarhi Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

That will sound unbelievable but it's enough to call '.toString()' on timestamp string. That will give human readable output

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your db connection config:

```
timezone: "America/Los_Angeles" // <-- change for whatever your TZ is
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the connection with option `dateString: true` to force date types to be returned as string.
Or you can also use custom type casting to pass a function and handle type casting yourself:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  // database properties...
  typeCast: function (field, next) {
    if (field.type === 'TIMESTAMP') {
        return field.string(); // or any format you want
    } else {
        return next();
    }
  }
});
```

Reference:

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#type-casting